# How can I add properties as nodes in a multi node tree picker in Umbraco 7?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

On my Umbraco site, I have My Product Holder, then Product Category Nodes, then Product Nodes. If I use a `Multi Node Tree Picker` with the Product holder as the root, the furthest I can go down is to the Product node. I want to be able to go one step further and have access to a property (`Merchello nodes`) which uses `GUID`. I How should I go about created the custom data type for this?

This is what I have so far: I created a custom picker, and I can load umbraco node ids (1095, 1096 etc), and it works great. However, when I pass a guid I get an error.

Here are the dialog options

```
var dialogOptions = {
    multiPicker: $scope.model.config.multiPicker,
    //entityType: entityType,
    entityType: "Member",       
    treeAlias: 'customcontent',
    section: 'customcontent', // $scope.model.config.startNode.type,
    customTreeParams: 'pageId=' + $routeParams.id + '&rootIds=' + $scope.merchelloNodeIds 
};
```

The problem is with '&rootIds=' + $scope.merchelloNodeIds, here the GUIDs are not loading correctly

Comment: The property exists on each Product node.

Comment: Please add some codes. What have you tried so far?